# Volume of air going through a hole with a temperature difference, and kWh of energy

Tags: thermodynamics, airflow, thermal-conduction

Let's say we have a square hole of 2cm x 2cm in a wall.
The inside temperature is 20°C, the outside temperature is 10°C, so $\Delta T = 10$.
This creates a flow of air. Let's say the velocity is $1\  m s^{-1}$.

The volume of air gone trough this hole during 1 hour seems to be $1.44\ m^3$, correct?

Which formula should we use to compute:

- the amount of energy (in Joule or kWh) "lost" from the inside ?

NB: we can assume there is very few air movement inside, and outside, no particular wind.

Comment: How will you know the direction of the airflow?

Comment: Missing is the flow rate for a start.

Comment: buy a handheld anemometer and get the velocity. work from there.

Comment: Why not just block the hole - saves any energy loss and unwanted draughts.

Comment: Just had new windows fitted - the windows are sealed son no air gaps are left. But the people who did the install are professionals...

Comment: You won't get wind or a draught from ΔT unless ΔT causes a ΔP (which it might if the warm, less dense air rises). Any difference in pressure between the sides of the house such as those caused by wind and vortices, would be much more significant.

Comment: @SolarMike Yes I am installing new windows, but I thought it would be a good opportunity to learn some thermodynamic formulas in the meantime :)

Comment: @Transistor Yes possible. Have you ever experienced this in a old house, near old windows in winter? you feel a flow of cold air from outside to inside, even if there is no wind outside. This is very classical, I have seen this many times in my life in many different places. Which typical value can we take for air flow speed ? Let's say 1 meter / second. How to compute the kWh lost in 1 hour if there is a $\Delta T$ of 10°C? Surface : 4 cm².

Comment: So calculate the amount of heat carried by each kg of air.

Comment: "... you feel a flow of cold air from outside to inside ...", yes, but if air is entering at one point it must be leaving at another. In older houses this might be the chimney or cooker extract hood or cavity wall ventilation points. There isn't going to be a typical value. It's possible to measure the house leakage by closing all the windows and running a calibrated extract fan at one door or window opening. The energy rating assessors will then measure the pressure differential between inside and outside with a higher diff indicating a more airtight house.

Answer (score 0):

One starting approximation can be using The air density difference as the driving force and equating the potential hydrostatic energy to the kinetic energy of the flow.
Assuming h and P are equal on both sides. The only variable is the density. And we will assume the difference in density is the driving force like a waterfall or weir pushing the air in through the hole.

At a temperature of 20°C and a pressure of 101.325 kPa, the density of dry air is approximately 1.2041 kg/m³ 1. At a temperature of 10°C, the density of dry air at the same pressure is approximately 1.2466 kg/m³

$1.2466-1.2041= 0.0425kg/m^3$

Source:engineeringtoolbox.com

The hydrostatic pressure of the cold side is the area of the square of 2 cm multiplied by the difference in density.

$0.0425=P_{density}$

$$P_{density} =F_{driving-force}$$

$$F= \dot m \alpha$$
From here it becomes a bit complicated. We need to know the time the flow regiment is under this acceleration to be able to calculate the v and Q. but we can assume this transitory path is proportional to the dimension of the opening.

This is just a motivation. The edges of the square the geometry of the room and the blowback condition will significantly affect the flow.

Comment: Thanks @kamran. Let's say the air flow comes through 2 cm x 2 cm square at 1 meter per second. How to compute the kWh heat lost in 1 hour, if $\Delta T$ is 10°C?

Comment: Assuming this is house there is no pressure differential across the hole and hence no flow due to pressure differential. There will be some flow due to buoyancy effects, as the hot air diffuses out through the hole, and cold air diffuses in. Of course a simpler case with a hole at the bottom and a hole at the top is much easier to think about, cold air will leak in at the bottom, and hot air will escape from the top. This is also more realistic for a house.

Comment: @GregLocock  there is definitely pressure, no matter if it is a house a gym, or a lab. the hydrostatic pressure $p=\rho*g*h$. if rho is higher the pressure is higher!

Comment: So if i were to run a water tube manometer between the inside and outside of a house you are expecting a pressure differential.

Comment: @Basj the Volume of air filtering through is 0.0004 m^3 /s. Energy needed=mass* specific heat of air*delta t=1.2466kg* 0.0004*1.005kJ(10 celsius)= 0.005016 kJ. therefore, 0.005016 *0.000277=0.000001389 kwatthour.

Comment: @GregLocock, if you run a sensitive pressure manometer even in the same room, you record different pressures, and those differences cause gentle drafts. In a vessel, a chamber, or a room there is always temperature stratification and convections and currents. We like to simplify nature to be able to isolate the phenomena we want to study!